# How can I force a compiler error if an un-overridden virtual method is called?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors, pragma

This is a rather general question about style and safety when writing a template base class in C++. Bear with me, though, there is a specific question at the end...

I have a template base class which fully implements the required functionality when the type T is a primitive type (int, float, etc.). However,if T is not primitive (for example, if T is a class that needs to have a constructor called with a specific set of arguments) then some of the methods will need to be overridden, and for this reason they are declared virtual in the template. The template also contains a pure virtual method which forces it to be abstract, so in order to be used it *must* be derived from: a derived class based on a primitive type can use all the methods as provided and override just the pure virtual one, whilst a derived class based on a non-primitive type should override all the virtual methods.

For example:

```
template <typename T> class myTemplate
{
public:
    // Constructor:
    myTemplate<T>();

    // Destructor:
    virtual ~myTemplate();

    // General function, valid for all classes derived from this:
    void printMe()
    {
        printf("Hello, I'm from the template\r\n");
    }

    // Primitive function, must be overridden for non-primitive types:
    virtual T DoSomething(const T& myClass)
    {
        T result = result + static_cast<T>(1);
        return result;
    }

    // Primitive function, must be overridden for non-primitive types:
    virtual T DoSomethingElse(const T& myClass)
    {
        T result = result - static_cast<T>(1);
        return result;
    }

    // Pure Virtual function, must be overridden in all cases:
    virtual void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const T& myClass) = 0
};


class myIntegerClass : public myTemplate<int>
{
public:
    virtual void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const int& myInteger) {} 
};
```

Suppose now I want to create a derived class where I expect 'DoSomething' to be called, but can't envisage any circumstances under which 'DoSomethingElse' would be useful. Therefore I'd like to reimplement 'DoSomething', but not bother with 'DoSomethingElse'. Nevertheless, if at some point the derived class's 'DoSomethingElse' method *does* get called (either because I really meant to call 'DoSomething' but wrote the wrong thing by mistake, or because a circumstance arose which I had earlier failed to envisage), then I want a compiler warning to be issued to remind me that I can't do this unless I reimplement 'DoSomethingElse' first.

For example:

```
class myWatermelonClass : public myTemplate<Watermelon>
{
public:
    virtual Watermelon DoSomething(const Watermelon &myWatermelon)
    {
          // Just return a copy of the original:
          Watermelon anotherWatermelon(myWatermelon);
          return anotherWatermelon;
    }

    virtual Watermelon DoSomethingElse(const Watermelon &myWatermelon)
    {
          // This routine shouldn't ever get called: if it does, then 
          // either I've made an error or, if I find that I really need
          // to reimplement it after all, then I'd better buckle down
          // and do it.
          < How do I make the compiler remind me of this? >
    }        

    virtual void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const Watermelon& myWatermelon) {}   
};
```

Obviously I know about the standard #error and #warning compiler directives, but if I use one of these then the error (or warning) is flagged every time I compile. What I want is to make sure that an error is given at compile time if I negligently call

```
DoSomethingElse(aSpecificWatermelon);
```

from somewhere in my code, *but not otherwise*. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is this just a fundamentally bad design in the first place?

Comment: Have you checked pure virtual methods?

Comment: "derived class based on a primitive type can use all the methods as provided and override just the pure virtual one, whilst a derived class based on a non-primitive type should override all the virtual methods" - looks like you should use a separate class inherited from myTemplate for your non-primitive types. In mytemplate all virtuals should be pure, and all functions except one should have implementation in the new class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misusing templates and virtual dispatch mix. For instance, you base class is not going to compile for any type that does not support addition operator and being constructible from an int. Every time `myTemplate` gets specialised implicitly, all the virtual functions *will* be compiled, even if you override them in derived classes:

```
virtual T DoSomething(const T& myClass)
{
    T result = result + static_cast<T>(1); // compile error when T == Watermelon
    return result;
}
```

In you case, what you are looking for is the explicit template specialisation:

```
template <>
class myTemplate<Watermelon>
{
public:
    // General function, valid for all classes derived from this:
    void printMe()
    {
        printf("Hello, I'm from the Watermelon template specialisation\r\n");
    }

    virtual Watermelon DoSomething(const Watermelon &myWatermelon)
    {
        // Just return a copy of the original:
        Watermelon anotherWatermelon(myWatermelon);
        return anotherWatermelon;
    }

    // notice there's no DoSomethingElse!

    virtual void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const Watermelon& myWatermelon) {}   
};
```

Now calling `DoSomethingElse` on an instance of `myTemplate<Watermelon>` will immediately give you a compile error, since there's no such function.

Comment: I think if my actual class more closely resembled the example I gave, then this would be the way to go. In practice, however, my actual 'myTemplate' doesn't have the static_casts in (I'm afraid these were the first things that popped into my mind as an example of something that would need to be overridden for non-primitive types) but does have a very large number of members (the great majority of which don't need to be overridden) and data fields which (when I did an experiment just now) weren't inherited from the  generic template by the specialised template.

Comment: Does your `myTemplate` have virtual members then?

Comment: Yes it does, but they are a small minority of the total number of members. The great majority of member functions don't need overriding, so I don't want to have to reimplement them in my specialised templates or in the final derived classes.

Comment: Then decompose the base type. `myTemplateBase<T>` can contain data members and functions not needing an override. `myTemplate<T>` and `myTemplate<Watermelon>` can both derive from it and supply specific functions or implement virtual ones.

Comment: I know this would work, but it's a more cumbersome solution than I'd hoped for. I was hoping that there was something in the language that would streamline this, but it's looking like there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

By using `static_assert`, you can cause a compile error when you try to call a function that doesn't meet certain criteria.  There is no need for virtual functions at all.  Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;

template <typename T>
struct myTemplate {
    void printMe() { cout << "Hello, I'm from the template\r\n"; }

    T DoSomething(const T& myClass)
    {
        static_assert(
          std::is_fundamental<T>::value,
          "DoSomething must be redefined in derived classes "
          "for non-fundamental types."
        );
        T result = myClass + static_cast<T>(1);
        return result;
    }

    T DoSomethingElse(const T& myClass)
    {
        static_assert(
          std::is_fundamental<T>::value,
          "DoSomethingElse must be redefined in derived classes "
          "for non-fundamental types."
        );
        T result = myClass - static_cast<T>(1);
        return result;
    }

    template <typename U>
    struct never_true { static const bool value = false; };

    void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const T&)
    {
        static_assert(
            never_true<T>::value,
            "RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll must be redefined "
            "in derived classes."
        );
    }
};

struct Watermelon {
};

struct Lemon {
};

struct myIntegerClass : myTemplate<int> {
  void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const int &) { }
};

struct myWatermelonClass : myTemplate<Watermelon> {
    Watermelon DoSomething(const Watermelon&)
    {
      return Watermelon();
    }

    Watermelon DoSomethingElse(const Watermelon&)
    {
      return Watermelon();
    }

    void RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(const Watermelon &) { }
};


struct myLemonClass : myTemplate<Lemon> {
};

int main()
{
    myIntegerClass x;
    x.DoSomething(5); // works
    x.DoSomethingElse(5); // works
    x.RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(5); // works
    myWatermelonClass y;
    y.DoSomething(Watermelon()); // works
    y.DoSomethingElse(Watermelon()); // works
    y.RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(Watermelon()); // works
    myLemonClass z;
    z.DoSomething(Lemon()); // error
    z.DoSomethingElse(Lemon()); // error
    z.RefrainFromDoingAnythingAtAll(Lemon()); // error
}
```

Comment: Note: this only works if `DoSomethingElse` is not a virtual function. Otherwise, it will fail an assertion for `myTemplate<Watermelon>`.

Comment: I like the look of this static_assert approach, but I want to try it out before I accept the answer. @gwiazdorrr's comment would be perfectly true if my real DoSomethingElse template function contained a static_cast, but in my actual template it does not.

Comment: Sadly I can't get this to work, since even when the member is overridden the static_assert still throws a compiler error. I guess this is the significance of the point made in @gwiazdorrr's answer, "every time myTemplate gets specialised implicitly, all the virtual functions *will* be compiled, even if you override them in derived classes", and also his comment above about this scheme only working if DoSomethingElse is not virtual.